# How to pull <stronG> value using JS

Tags: javascript, variables, google-tag-manager

Hope someone can help me here. Trying to pull  text only from screenshot below. When I use :

`document.getElementsByClassName("heading-2 color-blue")[0].textContent`

I get:
'SEALYON Yacht for Sale'  (I need only "SEALYON")

Thank you !

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate on how this is at all related to [tag:google-tag-manager]? Am I missing something?

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName("heading-2 color-blue")[0]` should return a `HTMLElement` object, so why not just call `getElementsByTagName('strong')[0]` on that return value before trying to access `textContent` to get what you’re after…?

Comment: @esqew Yes. I am creating custom javaScript variable in GTM to pull yacht name (under<strong>)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did the job :

`document.getElementsByClassName("heading-2 color-blue")[0].childNodes[0].innerText`